# Forge viewer Document.load throws exception on mobile devices

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are using Forge viewer version 3.2.x.

For ***Autodesk.Viewing.Document*** the function ***load(documentId,onSuccessCallback,onErrorCallback,accessControlProperties)*** the parameter *accessControlProperties* is listed as required (see [Autodesk Forge Documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/document/)). Not providing this parameter still works on Chrome / Firefox, but I discovered that missing the parameter causes problems on mobile devices. However, for this parameter there seems to be no example or specification available.

Maybe the problem is not the missing parameter itself but something else...? Getting the following exception in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:2300)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at each (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:923)
at invokeArrayArg (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:903)
at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:2294)
at new Autodesk.Viewing.GestureHandler (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:16042)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.createControls (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:44685)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:44758)
at GuiViewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:50852)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.start (viewer3D.js?v=3.2.*:44555)
```

Using *Viewer.loadDocument(documentId,onDocumentLoad,onLoadFailed,accessControlProperties)* is not an option, because we must load multiple models into the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late response, we have a backlog in the queue due to the IFC issue this week.

According to my experience, the `accessControlProperties` is not a required parameter for using `ViewingApplication.loadDocument()`. Could you consider providing a reproducible case demonstrating this issue to `forge.help@autodesk.com`? I'm glad to help you check what happened.

A non-confidential reproducible case contains following items:

- A **short** exact description of what you are trying to achieve.
- The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
- Some complete yet minimal sample models to run a test in. For example, Revit sample models here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html.
- A complete yet minimal Forge viewer app that can run and debugged.
- Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g. which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Eason - isolating the issue from our whole application was quite difficult, but made me finally find the problem myself:

We had a conflict with another JavaScript library that is included in our minified js file. The GestureRecognizer classes are named similar as in the camunda library which we are using for modelling bpmn processes. Solved it by excluding that library from the global js and include it only where it is needed, same as how we are dealing with forge library.